# Is Object c; and then c = new Integer(0); legit?

Tags: java

Let's suppose we have a variable type Object

```
Object c;
```

and suppose we want to instantiate it via wrapper. Is

```
c = new Integer(0);
```

legit?

I think it is because Object type is the "father" of every classes, such as of Integer which is a Wrapper class (upcast)

Comment: I think it is because Object type is the "father" of every classes, such as of Integer which is a Wrapper class (upcast)

Comment: What would make it *not* legit? It would be simpler to write `Object c = 0;` though.

Comment: What does the compiler tell you when you try to compile it?

Comment: I can't try via compiler right now. That was a pure teorical question

Comment: I would suggest in future waiting until you *can* try via a compiler to be honest, for questions like this. Yes, it's valid code... I'm not sure what there is to say beyond that, really.

Comment: There are also tools like https://ideone.com for those situations where you want to try something but all you have to hand is a browser.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, a variable with a reference type (such as `Object`) can hold a reference to an instance of any assignment-compatible reference type. Assignment-compatible reference types are:

- The variable's own reference type (`Object`, in your example).
- Any subclass of that type (`Integer` in your example, since `Integer` is a subclass of `Object`)
- If the variable's reference type is an interface, any class that implements that interface.

Sometimes, code seems to break those rules, such as:

```
Object c = 0; // Works just fine
```

That's because the `int` `0` is *autoboxed* into an `Integer` instance, and that instance's reference is stored in `c`.